# Get super (windows) key working again on Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, 18.04

Kubuntu 18.04, as a pleasant surprise, had the super key as shortcut for the application menu instead of the more traditional <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

I had to remove the panel and add a new one, and the super key didn't open the application menu any more. Now when I attempt to add a shortcut for the application menu, it doesn't allow just the super key by itself as the shortcut like in the old days.

How can I get the super key shortcut back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured out. Setting the shortcut to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> for the application menu automatically enables the super key as a shortcut for it.

Comment: If you have answered your own question read the advice here: https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer