# Win key (compose) shows Application Launcher in Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, compose-key

I'm trying to setup <kbd>Left-Win</kbd> as the compose key in Kubuntu 18.04.4. Problem: whenever I hit the key, the Application Launcher popups.

I read [in this AU-answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1037648/448034) that setting the shortcut <kbd>Alt+F1</kbd> for the launcher, automatically ALSO maps the <kbd>Win</kbd>-keys. Apparently, <kbd>Win</kbd>-key and <kbd>Alt+F1</kbd> are mapped to each other somehow?

## What I have done

System Settings -> Hardware -> Input Devices -> Keyboard -> Advanced -> Position of Compose key -> select Left Win

Also, the contents of `/etc/default/keyboard`:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc104"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT="euro"
XKBOPTIONS="lv3:ralt_switch,compose:lwin"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

## What works:

Pressing <kbd>Left-Win+e</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd> or <kbd>Left-Win+'</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> results in `é`. However, this only works *sometimes*, as if there is some toggling going on.

What I want (what I am used to) is that I can press <kbd>Left-Win</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> to get `é`. But this results in the popup of the Application Launcher :(

## Q

Perhaps the question is: how can I **unmap** <kbd>Left-Win</kbd> to <kbd>Alt+F1</kbd>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit *~/.config/kwinrc* to include the following section:

```
[ModifierOnlyShortcuts]
Meta=
```

Or, from a terminal, run

```
kwriteconfig5 --file kwinrc --group ModifierOnlyShortcuts --key Meta ""
```

Log out and log back in for the change to be effected.

---

Personally, I wouldn't use the <kbd>Win</kbd> key as the <kbd>Compose</kbd> key. It may clash with many of the preset keyboard shortcuts using <kbd>Win</kbd>. I set the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key for that purpose.

Comment: This actually works. Great, thanks. Choosing the "right" compose key is obviously a personal thing. I actually use CapsLock sometimes, not the Win key...